# How to write a utility of this JSON to return a value depending on the name passed

Tags: jquery

I wanted to utility of this JSON in such a way that if i pass the id , it must return the name .

I started as so that if the id matches , i can return the appropiate name as return type

```
for(var i = 0; i < json.length; i++) {
    alert(json[i].leaf[i].id)
}
```

but unfortunately I get

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property '0' of undefined

This is my fiddle

https://jsfiddle.net/a7okbf39/5/

Could you please let me know how to retrieve name based on the name passed fro the above JSON .

Comment: Given that the `leaf` property appears nested at different levels of the object structure you will need to use recursion use recursion to retrieve it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may use a simple javascript library to make manipulation and extraction of data from a JSON very easy and fast.

http://ignitersworld.com/lab/jsonQ.html#intro

```
function findbyId(id) {
    var family = jsonQ(jsonObj);
    //to find all the name which start with a
    var id = family.find('id', function () {
        return this == id
    });
    var name = id.sibling('name');
    return name.value();
}
console.log(findbyId('1247'));
```

I have updated the code please see below .

http://jsfiddle.net/kishoresahas/3wcy57qt/

Comment: thank you very much , in case the JSON has got multiple properties such as   id , name ,  cost , image . Is it possible to get all of them at once in form of array by passing the ID .

Comment: yes, you just have to pass the other property names and get the value separately and return as an object.

Comment: Ya , i am planning to form a string and return that , just wanted to check if the librray has got any functionality to return the array itself .

Comment: anyway thank you very much , thats of great help to me .

Answer (score 0):

As per the JSON data you have provided, the position of 'leaf' property is not fixed and may be more or less deeper per index. You can not access 'leaf' property directly as you used in the given 'for' loop.Instead you can check it inside jquery each concept. Here is the sample code may be use for your requirement.

```js
var result="";
var id="1246";

result = checkKey(json[0].item.T1,id); //-- used the deepest start --
console.log(result);

function checkKey(value,id)
{
 var temp = '';
 $.each(value, function(k, v) 
 {
  if(typeof v == "object")
  {
   if(v.hasOwnProperty('leaf'))
   {
    if(v.leaf[0].id == id) //-- check if id matches
    {
     temp = v.leaf[0].name;
     return false; //-- break loop
    }
   }
   else
   {
    temp = checkKey(v,id);
    return false; //-- break loop
   }
  }
  else
  {
   //--non-object
   temp = 1;
  }
 });
 if(temp !=1 && temp !='')
  return temp; // return only if desired result
}
```

Hope this helps!!